Google Authenticator for Accounts with non-Gmail Email Address As User Name
I have two email accounts, a business e-mail account on a private domain with the mail server on a third-party host and, separately, a Google account with its own, distinct, Gmail address.
Most or all of my online accounts with, e.g., banks, government agencies, and Stack Exchange exist with my private, non-Google email as the username for login purposes.
Now comes time to implement an authenticator and the question is, will Google Authenticator when set up on my Google account (with its own distinct email address) work for online accounts where the login credential is another email address?
Various searches don't turn up relevant information for this case, so any information that would save me the prospect of a cycle of configuration failures, would be most appreciated.

Yes - Google Authenticator just displays the 2FA codes.
The actual account usernames don't matter and are just used to identify what the TOTP code is for.
Google Authenticator uses your email to store the 2fa codes on the server so that it can be synced with other devices.
Few tips:
1: When setting up any account's 2FA, keep a backup of the setup key and / or QR code. You need to do this before closing the page that displays the setup information. Refreshing the page most likely will refresh the setup code/qr rendering the old one invalid.
Screenshot it and store it some place.
I add the setup key to my password manager. I also have it stored on my PC so that I can access it if I ever totally loose access to my 2FA codes.
I like to keep the key so that it can be added to authenticators / devices that don't have access to the camera.
This will make it easier down the road if you ever need to re-add it to an authenticator, or if you need to share it with someone.
This is really important if the Authenticator could be locked out if you can't login to your email account.
This almost happened to me with Google Authenticator: My main account which is used to log into the authenticator has 2FA.
I reset my phone - and couldn't log into my account on the phone or in Google Authenticator to sync the 2FA codes
Thankfully my tablet was still logged in so was able to get the needed code.
2: Some services do not have a way to recover an account if the 2FA information is lost. Backup any recovery codes they offer in addition to the above. If it is important enough, consider backing up in a way that 2FA is not needed to retrieve it.
3: Whatever Authenticator you use, regularly use its export feature to back up the data, and really should be backed up where 2FA is not needed if that Authenticator is the only source of 2FA codes
